# How to redirect requests coming on one domain to another domain but with parameters?

Tags: iis, rewrite

We have a website that is hosted on IIS7 and which is bound to several domains. The site is localized in multiple languages and part of the URL holds the language code, for example *www.mysite.com/en*, *www.mysite.com/cs*, *www.mysite.com/hu*, etc.

When the user requests the website under a country level domain, we would like to redirect them to the main (*.com*) domain, but add a language parameter, so that this should happen:

- user requests *www.mysite.cz* -> gets redirected to *www.mysite.com/cs*
- user requests *www.mysite.hu* -> gets redirected to *www.mysite.com/hu*

Is this possible with IIS URL Rewrite Module 2.0? If so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'll answer myself. Here's how to do this:

Go to the website in IIS and add a new rewrite rule.
Set Match URL to .*
Add a Condition, where {HTTP_HOST} matches the pattern of ^www.mysite.cz$
Add an Action of Redirect type and Redirect URL http://www.mysite.com/cs

Comment: lol, got downvoted on my own reply which is the correct & actual solution I used to my own problem. Great, thanks!